# how to load same models section in two diffrent pages

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

i have a model name section connected with other model name subject with foreign key what i want to do is i want to load half of it content in other page and half of it content on other html

my models.py

```
class Section(models.Model):
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='section')
    sub_section = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=5000, blank=False)
    teacher = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=False)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='section_vedios', blank=False)
    about_section = models.TextField(blank=False, default=None)
    price = models.FloatField(blank=False)
    content_duration = models.DurationField(blank=False)
    joined_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now,editable=False)
    update_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.subject.name
```

i mean i want to load {{section.title }} in one page and {{section.file }} on other when a person
click on the {{ section.title }}

here is my html

```
         <ul>
          {% for section in section_list %}
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
              {{ subject.name}}
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">{{ section.title }}</h5>
              <p class="card-text"></p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">CLick Here</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        {% endfor %}
```

so when a person click on click here a another load up and in that i want to load another html and in that file load only related {{section.file.url}} will open up

Answer (score 0):

if you want 2 pages, easy way is create generic view in views.py and write in class Section:

paginate_by = 2

this is complete tutorial:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/pagination/#paginating-a-listview

Comment: read the question properly this not what i asked for